# Getting kafka topic name using scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, alpakka

I am working  on a scala application in which I am using kafka. I want to retrieve topic names from my code. My code is as follows:

```
  def getTopic = {
    metadataClient.listTopics().map(x => logger.info(s"topic - $x"))
  }
```

And I am calling this method from my main class. On running it is not giving any errors. But When I call this method and store result in a val and print it. it says `Future(<not completed>)`. Also it is not printing value of x. How can I correct it.

Comment: I guess you're using `alpakka-kafka` right? `MetadataClient` offers this `listTopics` function that's `asynchronous`, meaning it'll return the result wrapped in a `Future` (specifically `Future[Map[String, List[PartitionInfo]]]`. Have a look at how to deal with Futures here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: yes I am using alpakka-kafka

Comment: how can I get result? @mfirry

Comment: Have a look at alpakka-kafka samples: https://github.com/akka/alpakka-samples/blob/master/alpakka-sample-http-csv-to-kafka/step_007_produce_to_kafka/src/main/scala/samples/Main.scala